# PageView Builder; Text is repeated through page view

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm building some pageview with a lot of text and want to scroll horizontally if the content exceed the screen

This is for reading, like a book. I've tried with the Text instead of RichText but got the same results.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(245, 205, 121, 1.0 ),
          title: Text('MyTitle'),
        ),
        body: 
        new PageView.builder(
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        controller: controller,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return new Center(
            child: new RichText(
              text:  TextSpan(style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.black), text: myText),
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              textScaleFactor: 1.0,
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,

              ),
            );
          },
          )
      )

    ); 
  }
var myText = "A Lot of text here"
```

I expect to have the continuation of lorem ipsum but I have the same content in all pages.[image: Same Text in all PageView]

Comment: you are passing the same `myText` to every page of `itemBuilder` so you see the same text on every page

Comment: @pskink How can I pass another text variables ?

Comment: put every page text in a list / array / whatever?

Comment: Edit: @pskink I tried to implement it with a list but it displays only the part of an element the screen can displays. And in another page, instead of continue the previous text element it started to display, it displays only the next text element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function will help you, I guess try this out.

```
  String currentPageText(int index, String myText) {
    // I assume 1000 is the length of the text that fits into your page, you can change it according to your page&textFont&textStyle
    if (index * 1000 < myText.length) {
      // you dont need the next line code if your index start from 1 but it can stay for a safety
      if (index == 0) return myText.substring(0, index * 1000); 

      return myText.substring((index - 1) * 1000, index * 1000);
    } else {
      if ((index - 1) * 1000 > myText.length) {
        return "Your Text Done"; // This is for your text finishes but your index still increases
      }
      return myText.substring((index - 1) * 1000, myText.length);
    }
  }
```

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(245, 205, 121, 1.0),
              title: Text('MyTitle'),
            ),
            body:
            new PageView.builder(
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              controller: controller,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return new Center(
                  child: new RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.black),
                        text: currentPageText(index, myText)),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    textScaleFactor: 1.0,
                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,

                  ),
                );
              },
            )
        )

    );
  }
```

[example to see in dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/99ff8969348d9b2ec319cfbc894ee157)

Comment: is it normal your function only display "Your Text Done" ? @ciplionat

Comment: Now it displays only the first characters it can do in a screen, and repeat this in all others screen.

Comment: It should display's the parts of your string as I provide a dart pad example above but if your string parts finished and you're still try to increase the index(Pagaview index change) now you should see the "Your Text Done".

Comment: Unfortenately it displays the first part of my string my screen can display and repeats it in all the others pages. Text doesn’t continue.

Comment: Can you post an gif and also check Is the index changes after you change the page ?

Comment: It works without anything added. The only problem is the "Your Text done" which is repeated.